# How to write a multi thread lua script or just let multiple scripts run together in a c++ program

Tags: c++, multithreading, lua

I have a c++ program.It contains several functions and works well in c++.
Now I want to write a lua/c++ embedded program to help the tester(sometimes they do not know programming) test the functions.Not even consists different function permutation and combination,but also will use multi thread. For example,functions are called as ABCD,or BACD,DCBA... The sequences are uncertain.They need to adjust the params for every functions.
And sometimes,two or more threads are needed to run at the same time.

Every lua script contains a endless loop and I want to run them at the same time.How could I do?

```
lua_State *L;
L = luaL_newstate();
luaopen_base(L);
luaL_setfuncs(L, mylib, 0);
luaL_dofile(L, "test1.lua");  // start thread1
luaL_dofile(L, "test2.lua");  // start thread2

return 0;
```

Comment: Create separate `lua_State` for each test and run them in parallel.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I opened several  threads in c++, every thread creates a state and dofile,It works very well.

Comment: Is there any solution to share the data between two threads?

Comment: Pick some mechanism for passing data between threads in plain C++, then write some Lua wrappers for it.

Comment: You can serialize Lua data, pass it to another thread (using C code) and deserailize it.  Look also at [lualanes](http://lualanes.github.io/lanes/)

Comment: Thanks for all your replies.This is helpful for me.